# Does the Oracle in the Matrix have anything to do with an oracle machine in computer science?

Tags: the-matrix, the-matrix-revolutions, the-matrix-reloaded

An [oracle machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) as defined by Alan Turing is a Turing machine connected to an oracle which can solve non-computable problems in a single operation, most famously the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). The halting problem is the problem of determining whether any arbitrary computer program will eventually halt or continue to loop forever.

I'm wondering if the Oracle character in the series could be seen as inspired by this concept, but I can't remember the plot well enough to determine.

Comment: It seems unlikely. There were very few references to genuine computer science in the movie, and that reference would be particularly obscure.

Answer (score 6):

The Oracle's main function is to counterbalance the Architect.  It was the Oracle and the Architect who built The Matrix, and the events in the trilogy are actually taking place in the **third** Matrix, as the first 2 failed.  The Oracle stands for free will, whereas the Architect stands for order.  As a result, I'd find it difficult to tie Turing's oracle into the plot.

Comment: Turing's oracle has nothing to do with free will.

Comment: Please re-read the Wiki on Turing and Oracle.  Your understanding of them is completely wrong.  It would make more sense to base the character on the definition of "Oracle" in Webster's dictionary.

Comment: "An oracle machine can be conceived as a Turing machine connected to an oracle. The oracle, in this context, is an entity capable of solving some problem, which for example may be a decision problem or a function problem."  And so, Turing's machine **requires** an oracle.  For all intents and purposes, an oracle is defined by Webster's, so why would a character in a movie be based on some **hypothetical** machine that has nothing to do with the oracle, but needs an oracle to operate?

Comment: @svenoaks Rather they were aware of Greek mythology or whatever else general and universally known definition of what an oracle is.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Feel free to add your recent insights from the comments into the answer.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It is true that Turing's oracle has nothing to do with free will. However it's not the only kind of oracle being used in computer science. For example a branch of cryptography centers around the concept of a random oracle. (Not that randomness has anything to do with free will either.)

Comment: The difference between the Architect and Oracle isn't just order vs free will, it's logical intelligence versus emotional intelligence. The Architect (much like Smith) is shown to not comprehend human behavior when it defies cold logic. In order to build the Matrix, it must be believed by humans (remember how they rejected the first utopian Matrix - the Oracle probably didn't do QA on that one). The Oracle's people skills provide insight that the Architect himself sorely lacks.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, [oracles would allow Turing machines to go beyond logic](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22329780-400-turings-oracle-the-computer-that-goes-beyond-logic/), since they're able to solve problems in constant time; that relates them to imagination or freedom of will and thus to the Oracle in the movie. Of course, it's not an implementation, but it's plausible enough.